# Using Left: 0 and Right: 0 on the same element?

Tags: html, css, position

I understand the principle of `left:` and `right:` positioning if you want to position an element inside it's parent and then add the appropriate values to position the element where necessary.  I saw a site today where a lot of the elements had the left and right properties both set to 0.

#### Example:

```
div {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

This was the case on a number of `fixed` and `relative` positioned `<div>`s.  Surely you can't fix a `<div>` so it's positioned both left and right to zero? Could someone explain if this is valid CSS, and if so, please explain what it achieves.

Many thanks,

Emily

Comment: http://keithjgrant.com/posts/2016/01/width-and-absolute-positioning/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is valid CSS. Basically, code like this will center absolute divs. Just remember to also add this code: `margin: auto;`. Here's a working example:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```